# How to get "price_retail" field value in tempate?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-oscar

I am trying access `price_retail` field in product detail page using template tag `purchase_info_for_product`. but am not getting the value of `price_retail`.

```
 {% purchase_info_for_product request product as session %}
    {{ session.price.price_retail|currency:session.price.currency }}
```

but i am able to access fields like `incl_tax, excl_tax`

Comment: I think that attribute (`price_retail`) is only available on `stockrecord` objects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access a field from the stock record - this is not the same as the `Price` object that the strategy provides.

The stock record is available on the parent object though, and can be accessed with:

```
session.stockrecord.price_retail
```

Note: The `price_retail` field will be removed in [Oscar 2.1](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/a8f861fba4f7a5bc4664a239ab42a6ae78d6eea0/src/oscar/apps/partner/abstract_models.py#L122-L123)